# A question on ordinal arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic, ordinals

I have to order these two ordinals and I was just wondering if I have done it correctly.

$\omega^\omega + \omega^3$ and $\omega + \omega^3 +\omega^\omega$

I have worked out that $\omega + \omega^3 + \omega^\omega = \omega^\omega$
and that $\omega^\omega + \omega^3 = \omega^{\omega + 3}$

so $\omega^\omega + \omega^3 > \omega + \omega^3 +\omega^\omega$

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it is not. $\omega^{\omega+3}$ is different from $\omega^\omega+\omega^3$.

Comment: I have noticed that you have not accepted any answers to your questions, even though you have received several good, thorough and complete ones in the past. This in general discourages people from spending the time to answer your queries...

Comment: Hello, I'm not really sure I understand what you mean when you say that 'you have not accepted answers to your questions.' If you mean that I question the answers that people give me, I am merely asking for clarification and I don't think it really 'discourages' anyone. But if you mean that I have not said thank you for any of the answers people give then I am deeply sorry but it does not appear to be normal practice on this site.

Comment: @user200632: *Accepting an answer* has a specific technical meaning that is explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). If you get at least one good answer to your question, it is good manners to accept the best one: this rewards people for providing useful answers and gives you a small reward for helping the system to work as intended. It also increases the likelihood of your getting good answers by demonstrating that you understand and are willing to work within the site’s dynamics. (And despite ...

Comment: ... what the Stack Exchange system says, it is not in fact very unusual for users to thank those who provide them with especially helpful answers.)

Comment: Your inequality holds true but your reasoning as to why is not correct (as pointed out above).